# How to support object Serialization and Deserialization for changing class structure with .net?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an entity class which can change over period of time. As of now, I binary serialization to serialize an object of this class. But if I add a new property to the class, I can't deserialize a stream serialized earlier. I tried if I can use `BSON` with `json.net`.

I need to take care of these things:

- Memory footprint of serialized data should be low
- serialization and deserialization should be fast
- Need to provide backward compatibility for data serialized with old entity class structure

One approach I considered is to convert the object to `IDictionary` before serializing it so that I can set default value to properties that are not matching while deserializing. While this works well, it involves additional step to convert the object to `IDictionary`.

Has anyone faced this situation? what are the approaches you use?

Comment: Have you looked at Version Tolerant Serialization: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Text-based json with type-hinting can solve the backwards compatibility issue, but may not meet your memory and performance needs.

Comment: @yoyo json based approach doesn't work that well for me as quantum of data is huge

Comment: Fair enough, just thought I'd mention it. If anyone else comes here looking for information on backwards-compatible serialization perhaps it will help them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually binary serialization is very flexible. Of course, you can just add `[Serializable]` attribute to the class and forget about details, but you can also take the full control on serialization by implementing [ISerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface/by adding methods/attributes which corresponds to the certain steps of serialization/deserialization lifecycle. Considering your question about structure changes, please take a look on the [following article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).